# Unable to install Ubuntu on older ThinkPad

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, thinkpad, pxe

I bought an older ThinkPad (Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E325).

I created a bootable USB flash drive. Everytime I try to install Ubuntu, it works well and everything is fine until it asks me to restart. So I do that, unplug the USB drive after the display has turned black. Then the laptop goes on again, displays the opening (Lenovo ThinkPad) goes off and on again to go to show me

> For Atheros PCIE Ethrnet Controller v2.0.2.7(11/02/10)
> Check cable connection!
> PXE-MOF: Exeting INtel  PXE ROM

then it displays

> No operating system found.

However, if I install Ubuntu again, I get the option to install Ubuntu alongside Ubuntu.

Is there anything I can to in the way I setup the install media or how the laptop boots? or has is something to do with UEFI?

Comment: did you install grub to the internal HD?

Comment: what is that and how can i do it ?

Comment: "That" is something you should know/be aware of when installing Ubuntu since it's Ubuntu's default bootloader. Likewise, you should be aware of difference between installing in UEFI or Legacy mode (E325 is an early UEFI so UEFI mode should be preferred). What's happening is - probably - you've installed Ubuntu in one mode and are booting with another (the message merely states it tried to find a bootable instance in the network and it failed as expected).

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from the Ubuntu installer in its "try before installing" mode and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but having struggled myself with the very same issue with E325 for two way too long evenings I will post my solution:

Background:

- E325 has two boot modes: UEFI and Legacy. BIOS can be configured for exclusively one or the other, or both.
- Apparently UEFI boot mode of E325 has some compatibility kinks, this was a pretty new feature back in the day
- While installing Linux from USB disk, the installer automatically detects the boot method that was used to boot the USB stick, and configures the installed OS to use same boot method.
- I tried to install Ubuntu 22 LTS Mate first. The USB booted in UEFI mode but not on Legacy. The installed OS did not boot. I assume that the legacy boot support has been dropped from the installer.
- Then I tried to install Ubuntu 18 LTS (maybe specific MATE version, not sure). The stick was able to boot in both modes. The UEFI installed OS did not boot, but the Legacy-boot installed OS did work!

So the solution:

- Ubuntu 18 LTS installer ISO and write it on USB stick
- To enter boot menu on startup, press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
- Set the boot mode to legacy only (might also need to adjust boot order so that USB stick is first)
- Boot from the USB and install. It should work.